# Spring MVC 3.2 Jackson Bad Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, datatables

I migrated from Spring 3.1 to Spring 3.2.5. before migrating to Spring 3.2.5 everything seems to be working howerver when I updated my library some of my rest calls are returning a 400 Bad Request.

Here's the method

```
    @RequestMapping(value = AJAX_SEARCH_MED)
    @ResponseBody
    DataTablesAjaxResponse<ActiveMedicationView> ajaxSearchActiveMedication(
            @PathVariable(PATH_PIN) String pin,
            @RequestBody DataTablesAjaxRequest request);
```

I already configured my mvc:annotation to this

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <!-- Turn off working out content type based on URL file extension, should fall back to looking at the Accept headers -->
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
</bean>
```

in my pom. I have this jackson marshalling library

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.10</version>
  </dependency>
```

However when making calls from data tables I always receive a bad request.

[image]

The code calling the method

```
$('#prescriptionsTable').dataTable({
        "bProcessing":true,
        "bServerSide":true,
        "bFilter":false,
        "sAjaxSource":"/cms/ajax/patient/2012010000000009/active-medication.html",
        "aoColumnDefs":[ //Other configurations here
```

Comment: First, turn your logs to debug and see what Spring says.

Comment: Show us the logs for a full request cycle.

Comment: Can you please show us the code calling this api and also the full body of the method so we can see what is being processed and returned

Comment: @Aeseir added the code calling the API. also. the method only contains the logging.

Comment: Server-side logs, not client-side.

Comment: So what exactly does the return code send back? Can you show that?

Comment: Is see that your datatables POST its data. Is this what you want? You can change this with the option "sServerMethod": "GET" or change the @RequestMapping in Spring to method = RequestMethod.POST.

BTW: Why don't you use the new datatables (1.10) or if you use that version, why keep using the legacy options? (like "bProcessing" is now just "processing" with DataTables 1.10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this configuration:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = AJAX_SEARCH_MED, method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Content-Type=application/json")
        @ResponseBody
        public DataTablesAjaxResponse<ActiveMedicationView> ajaxSearchActiveMedication(
                @PathVariable(PATH_PIN) String pin,
                @RequestBody DataTablesAjaxRequest request)
{
// random code
};
```

If this doesn't fix it we can try to dig further to identify the problem.

Comment: I just tried it. it returned me Error 405: "Request Method Post not supported"

Comment: try the headers trick i just added. If that doesn't work then its purely client side.